# What kind of normalization is used in my code?

Tags: c#, neural-network, normalization

I try to found out, how to work [this code](https://code.google.com/p/meuprojetofinal/source/browse/trunk/Algoritmos/NeuralNetworkDemo/Demo2D_Draw.cs).

```
public class UnPoint 
{
    public int X, Y;
    public float x, y;
    public float v;

    public static float X_MIN = -1f;
    public static float X_MAX = 1f;
    public static float Y_MIN = 0f;
    public static float Y_MAX = 1f;

    public UnPoint(int XX, int YY, int w, int h) 
    {
        X = XX;
        Y = YY;
        x = (X_MAX-X_MIN) / ( (float)(w-1) ) * ( (float)X ) + X_MIN;
        y = (Y_MAX-Y_MIN)/((float)(h-1))*((float)((h-1) - Y)) + Y_MIN;
    }
}
```

What is **x, y**? I think, that it is some kind of normalization. But I don't find type of this.

I'll be glad to any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is normalizing a value `XX` from the interval `[0 w-1]` into the interval `[-1 +1]` and a value `YY` from the interval `[0 h-1]` to the inverse location in the interval `[0 1]`.

E.g. it can normalize screen coordinates from (0,0) in the upper left corner, to (w-1, h-1) in the lower right corner, so the left edge of the screen is `X_MIN` (-1), the right edge of the screen is `X_MAX` (+1), the top edge of the screen is `Y_MAX` (1) and the bottom edge of the screen is `Y_MIN` (0).